# How to "fake" a session in a web app for testing?

Tags: session, web-applications, junit

I want to Test a Struts App with JUnit and have a problem with the Logout.
It should work by destroying the session-cookie.

Therefor I need a Session to be able to logout.
Can you tell me, how to generate one, without having a Browser, or so?

Comment: There is `MockHttpSession` in spring test project.

Comment: What does this mean? Sorry! I'm Quite new to Unit Testing!

Comment: There is spring-test jar in which there is `MockHttpSession` class which you can use to mock http session. http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.springframework|spring-test|4.1.4.RELEASE|jar.